# Extending subclass instances from superclass instances in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Is there any way to instantiate a subclass object as an extension of a superclass object, in such a way that the subclass retains the arguments passed to the superclass?

I'm working on a simple melody generator to get back into programming. The idea was that a Project can contain an arbitrary number of Instruments, which can have any number of Sequences.
Every subordinate object would retain all of the information of the superior objects (e.g. every instrument shares the project's port device, and so forth).

I figured I could do something like this:

```py
import rtmidi

class Project:
    def __init__(self, p_port=None):
        self.port = p_port   

    # Getter / Setter removed for brevity

class Instrument(Project):
    def __init__(self, p_channel=1)
        self.channel = p_channel

    # Getter / Setter removed for brevity

def port_setup():
    midi_out = rtmidi.MidiOut()
    selected_port = midi_out.open_port(2)
    return selected_port

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = port_setup()
    project = Project(p_port=port)
    project.inst1 = Instrument()
    print(project.port, project.inst1.port)
```

The expectation was that the new instrument would extend the created Project and inherit the port passed to its parent.

However, that doesn't work; the project and instrument return different objects, so there seems to be no relation between the objects at all. A quick Google search also doesn't turn up any information, which I assume means I'm really missing something.
Is there a proper way to set up nested structures like this?

Comment: Pro tip: avoid inheritance, prefer composition.

Comment: "Getter / Setter removed for brevity" **don't write getters and setters at all in Python**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relationship is that each `Project` *has* many `Instruments`. An `Instrument` is not a `Project`.

One first step could be to tell each `Instrument` which project is belongs to:

```py
import rtmidi

class Project:
    def __init__(self, p_port=None):
        self.port = p_port   

    # Getter / Setter removed for brevity

class Instrument:
    def __init__(self, project, p_channel=1)
        self.project = project
        self.channel = p_channel

    # Getter / Setter removed for brevity

def port_setup():
    midi_out = rtmidi.MidiOut()
    selected_port = midi_out.open_port(2)
    return selected_port

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = port_setup()
    project = Project(p_port=port)
    project.inst1 = Instrument(project)
    print(project.port, project.inst1.project.port)
```

Comment: `Project` should probably take `Instrument` as an argument

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work by just passing on the "parent" as an argument instead of trying to use subclasses. Edit: I think I may have accidentally tried to edit your post(?), which I obviously didn't intend to do.